# Proving this upper bound involving VC dimension

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

Let $S_n = \{ (x_i, y_i)\}^n_{i=1}$ be a data set. Let $\mathcal H$  and $\mathcal H' $ be hypothesis classes, such that $\mathcal H' = \{ h \in \mathcal H: \hat {er}_{S_n}(h) \leq \beta\}$, where $\hat {er}_{S_n}(h) = \sum^n_{i=1}\mathcal I[y_i \neq h(x_i)]$ is the empirical error of $h$ on $S_n$ and $\beta \geq 0$.

I need to prove that
$$ 3 \sqrt {\frac{\log (2 |\mathcal H'(S_n)|)}{n}} = \mathcal O(\sqrt {\beta \frac{\text{VC}(\mathcal H) \log (\frac{en}{\text{VC}(\mathcal H)}))}{n}}), $$
where $|\mathcal H'(S_n)| = \{ (h(x_1), \dots, h(x_n)): h \in \mathcal H'\}$, and VC refers to the VC-dimension.

This is my attempt using Sauer's lemma: $$ 3 \sqrt {\frac{\log (2 |\mathcal H'(S_n)|)}{n}} \leq 3 \sqrt {\frac{\log (2)   +\log (|\mathcal H(S_n)|)}{n}}\leq 3\sqrt {\frac{\log 2 + \text{VC}(\mathcal H)\frac{en}{\text{VC}(\mathcal H)}}{n}}.$$

How can I make $\beta$ appear?

Comment: Your target bound doesn't make sense - as $\beta$ decreases, $\mathcal{H}'$ grows but the upper bound decreases. Do you mean to have $\hat{\mathrm{er}}_{S_n} \le \beta$ in the definition of $\mathcal{H}'$?

Comment: @stochasticboy321: Yes, it was the other around.

Comment: I don't think this is true - take the class of single stumps in $[0,1].$ The VC dimension is $1$, and you want to show that $\log |\mathcal{H}'(S_n)| = O(\beta \log n).$ Take $S_n$ that is exactly realised by a single stump. Even then, there are $2\beta n$ different stumps that get up to $\beta n$ labels correct, ergo $\log |\mathcal{H}'(S_n)| = \log(2\beta n).$ This does not decay linearly in $\beta$ - e.g. take $\beta = 1/\log\log n,$ then the target upper bound is $o(\log n),$ while $\log(\beta n) = \Theta(\log n)$.

Comment: Or worse, take $\beta = 1/\sqrt{n}$. N.B. I'm not overscaling here - if $\beta = \Omega(1),$ then the bounds are the same order-wise anyway, and so it's not clear what you're looking for. If $\beta$ does decay with $n$, then the interesting regime is $n\beta \to \infty, n\to \infty, \beta \to 0,$ which is precisely the sort of $\beta$s I'm considering.